# Restart individual rails apps in nginx+unicorn

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, unicorn

I have 15-20 independent rails applications on the same ec2 instance. The rails applications are deployed 
using apache + passenger with Railsbaseuri.

```
RailsBaseURI /games
<Directory /home/ubuntu/vol/sports/public/games>
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

If i update any rails application, i have to reload/restart apache accordingly depending on the change in assets which slows down the other running applications. I want to avoid affecting other applications and would like to reload individual applications.
I'm would also like to know if this can be achieved using nginx+unicorn if in case apache is not having any solution for this.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with passenger. But any other server should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of Nginx+Unicorn will work for you. If not, maybe Passenger **Enterprise**, which has rolling restarts feature.

Comment: I'll be checking with that.thanx